# How do I generate recursive ctags without Exuberant Ctags?

Tags: macos, vim, ctags

I recently took a new job as a software developer for a company with a large and complicated primary software package, with many different hooks depending on how your new code wants to integrate with the old code. This is all well and good, except as a new employee I'm not yet familiar with the overall structure of the source code and often cannot find the project code that I'm looking for.

The whole svn repository is stored on my local computer under ~/Documents/trunk. I want to be able to generate a ctags file so that I can quickly jump to symbol definitions from within vim so I can learn what different pieces of code do. Unfortunately, I do not have admin access to this computer so I cannot install Exuberant Ctags to make my life easy; I have to remain with the version of ctags that ships on OS X.

How can I generate tags such that vim can find symbols even if they are defined in another subfolder of trunk? I wrote a simple bash script to hopefully generate the tags, but that does not seem to work. The script is simply:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(find . -name '*.cpp' -or -name '*.h')
do
ctags -w -d $i
done
```

Like I said though, this doesn't work, so any ideas for how to solve this are much-appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you compile Exuberant Ctags from source, put it somewhere to `~/Documents/my-stuff/` for example, then do `export PATH=~/Documents/my-stuff:$PATH`

Comment: Because I'm an idiot :) Thanks for the help!